# How to MOVE or COPY multidimensional dynamic arrays to matlab`s arrays

Tags: matlab, delphi, delphi-7, dynamic-arrays

If I use non-dynamic arrays, all works

```
    pmxArray = mxArray^;
    perA_ptr: pmxArray;
    perA: array[1..3,1..4] of double;

    perA_ptr := mxCreateDoubleMatrix(4,3,mxREAL);
    Move(perA, mxGetPr(perA_ptr)^, 4*3*sizeof(double));
    ......
    _mlflinprog1(1,perX_ptr,perF_ptr,perA_ptr,perB_ptr,perLB_ptr);
```

it's WORKS.

but i need to use dynamic arrays. And i have a problem

```
perA: array of array of Double;
SetLength(perA,4,3);
perA_ptr := mxCreateDoubleMatrix(4,3,mxREAL);
Move(perA, mxGetPr(perA_ptr)^, 12*sizeof(double));
```

doesnt work, only trash in array;

`Move(perA[0,0], mxGetPr(perA_ptr)^, 4*sizeof(double));`  - WORKS for first row, but i need to copy all array's data, IDK how to do that in delphi.

That's arrays I need for matlab c shared library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your static array is stored in one contiguous block. A two dimensional dynamic array is ragged. In C terms you have `double**`. Although a Delphi array has extra book keeping, that's how you need to think of it.

So when you do

```
SetLength(perA, 4, 3);
```

you have an array `perA` of length 4, each of whose elements is another array. Each inner array is of length 3. The 3 elements of each inner array are stored contiguously, but these arrays are not contiguous. Therefore you'll need to copy the rows one at a time.

Exactly how you implement this depends on whether your Delphi matrix is stored row-major or col-major. If the former then it's simplest to populate a matrix and then transpose it. The code for both variants might look like this:

```
type
  TDoubleMatrix = array of array of Double;

function CreateDoubleMatrixColMajor(nRow, nCol: Integer): TDoubleMatrix;
begin
  SetLength(Result, nCol, nRow);
end;

function CreatemxArrayFromColMajor(const M: TDoubleMatrix): PmxArray;
var
  col: Integer;
  nRow, nCol: Integer;
  values: PDouble;
begin
  nCol := Length(M);
  Assert(nCol > 0);
  nRow := Length(M[0]);
  Assert(nRow > 0);

  result := mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nRow, nCol, mxREAL);
  values := mxGetData(result);
  for col := 0 to nCol - 1 do
  begin
    Assert(Length(M[col]) = nRow);
    Move(M[col], values^, nRow * SizeOf(Double));
    inc(values, nRow);
  end;
end;

function CreateDoubleMatrixRowMajor(nRow, nCol: Integer): TDoubleMatrix;
begin
  SetLength(Result, nRow, nCol);
end;

function CreatemxArrayFromRowMajor(const M: TDoubleMatrix): PmxArray;
var
  row: Integer;
  nRow, nCol: Integer;
  tmp: PmxArray;
  values: PDouble;
begin
  nRow := Length(M);
  Assert(nRow > 0);
  nCol := Length(M[0]);
  Assert(nCol > 0);

  tmp := mxCreateDoubleMatrix(nCol, nRow, mxREAL);
  values := mxGetData(tmp);
  for row := 0 to nRow - 1 do
  begin
    Assert(Length(M[row]) = nCol);
    Move(M[row], values^, nCol * SizeOf(Double));
    inc(values, nCol);
  end;
  mexCallMATLAB(1, @result, 1, @tmp, 'transpose');
  mxDestroyArray(tmp);
end;
```

I've not even compiled any of this code. All my Matlab programming is done in C. But I think that the above should have the ideas that you need.

Comment: Since it was built off of Fortran packages, MATLAB is column major.

Comment: ShowMessage(FloatToStr(mxGetPr(perA_ptr)^));   return 0 , wiil be 1; How to assign P to perA_ptr?

Comment: P is a pointer to the internal double array in the mxArray. That's what `mxGetPr` returns. You called `mxGetPr` too.

Comment: Thank you very much, but i know that, and  perA_ptr is empty D: only zeroes inside;  And perA_ptr:=mxTranspose(perA_ptr)    for transposing

Comment: `mxTranspose` is an undocumented function that is gone in recent releases. Don't call it.

Comment: Ah, my call to `Move` was wonky. Destination must be `P^` and not `P`. I've lashed this up in a hurry. Please don't assume that I've debugged it, or executed it. Please make sure you understand the concepts. You clearly know your way around Matlab. I'm sure you can work it out with the knowledge that multi-dimensional dynamic arrays are nested arrays.

Comment: P :=  mxGetPr(perA_ptr);
  for Row := 0 to high(perA) do
  begin
  Move(Pointer(perA[Row])^, P^, SizeOf(Double)*Length(perA[Row]));
  inc(P, Length(perA[Row]));
  end;
  perA_ptr:=mxTranspose(perA_ptr);

Comment: Don't call `mxTranspose`. Because when you upgrade your Matlab, you will be load time link error.

Comment: It need for matlab2010

Comment: When you run your program on a later version, it will fail with a load time link time error. Because `mxTranspose` has been removed. `mexCallMATLAB` is known to work, and is supported. Anyway, I've made my point. It's your decision, not mine. Good luck!!  :-)